# View object not clickable - using OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I created a basic Class called ListItem, which just stores two Strings and an integer.

This is my container for items that sit in a RecyclerView.

I tried to make ListItems clickable, so I made the ListItem extend the View class. And then added an OnClickListener and set it. It hasn't worked. I tested by creating a short message using TOAST but nothing displays. Does anyone have any idea why?

ListItem class:

```
  public ListItem(String title, String date, int url, Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    this.title = title;
    this.date = date;
    this.url = url;
}
```

...class where ListItems are created.....

```
    private AttributeSet attrs;


  ListItem y = new ListItem(title, date, a, this.getContext(), attrs);


    View.OnClickListener mFan = new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    };

    y.setOnClickListener(mFan);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for this in the View class.

```
y.setClickable(true);
```

<s>You may also need to do this for the ListView as well.</s>

<s>myListView.setClickable(true);</s>

Comment: No need to do for ListView itself.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing item click listener in RecyclerView is a bit different.

I assume you have implemented your own custom RecyclerViewAdpater which should be like this. You have to implement your own OnClickListener interface inside it.

```
public class CustomRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItem> listItems;

    private static OnListItemClickListener onListItemClickListener;

    public interface OnListItemClickListener {

        public void onListItemClick(int position, View v);

    }

    public void setOnListItemClickListener(OnListItemClickListener onListItemClickListener) {

        this.onListItemClickListener = onListItemClickListener;

    }

    // You implement OnClickListener in your list item view holder.
    public static class ListItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ListItemViewHolder(View listItemView) {

            super(listItemView);

            listItemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            onListItemClickListener.onListItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);

        }

    }

}
```

Then in your main activity or fragment you would do something like this.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

CustomRecyclerViewAdapter customRecyclerViewAdapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(listItems);

recyclerView.setAdapter(customRecyclerViewAdapter);

customRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnListItemClickListener(new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter.OnListItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(int position, View v) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

});
```

Comment: Hi @javapalava! Please accept as answer if this helped you. Thanks!